# An introductory book on varieties and smooth algebraic curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, book-recommendation, algebraic-curves, affine-varieties

I'm looking for an introductory book on varieties and smooth algebraic curves. I know there are many such books, but most are too advanced and/or have the material in middle chapters built upon various previous chapters. I just want learn the basics of affine and projective varieties and algebraic curves (e.g. proof of Riemann-Roch). My aim is to learn this to get by for studying elliptic curves before I learn algebraic geometry properly. I'd also like you to  point out if this plan is ill-advised.

Comment: As to the last part of your post, algebraic geometry is such a vast subject that it's usually best to enter it by studying specific objects, as you're doing

Comment: @leibnewtz Thanks for confirming that; I needed to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Kirwan's "Complex Algebraic Curves"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521423538) to be quite good entry level material.

Comment: Thank you very much! It appears to be exactly what I was seeking!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)